# Searching recursively for files to add to list, but if one type of file is found ignore other type

Tags: python

How can I search recursively for files to add to a list, but if one type of file is found ignore another type?

Here is my current code:

```
import os
import fnmatch

rootDir = "//path/to/top/level/directory"

ignore = ['ignoreThisDir','ignoreThisToo']

fileList = []

for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(rootDir):
    for idir in ignore:
        if idir in dirnames:
            dirnames.remove(idir)

    for name in files:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, 'A.csv') or fnmatch.fnmatch(name, 'B.csv'):
            fileList.append(os.path.join(dirpath, name))
```

Currently this code is partially working for me. It takes a top level directory and searches down recursively through the directory tree creating a list of directories and files within, removing the directories that I don't want the code to os.walk through.

But there is one extra step I can't work out.

If B.csv exists in a directory, I only want to append *it*, and not A.csv. But if B.csv is *not* found then I *do* want to append A.csv to my list of files.

My current code appends both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If B.csv exists in a directory, I only want to append it and not A.csv. But if B.csv is not found then I do want to append A.csv to my list of files.

There are two ways to do this.

---

First, you can make two passes through the directory: first search for B.csv, then, only if it wasn't found, search for A.csv. Like this:

```
for name in files:
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, 'B.csv'):
        fileList.append(os.path.join(dirpath, name))
        break
else:
    for name in files:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, 'A.csv'):
            fileList.append(os.path.join(dirpath, name))
            break
```

(If you've never seen a `for…else` before, the `else` part triggers if you finished the `for` loop without hitting a `break`—in other words, if you didn't find B.csv anywhere.)

---

Alternatively, you can remember that you found A.csv, but not add it until you know that you haven't found B.csv:

```
a = b = None
for name in files:
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, 'A.csv'):
        a = name
    elif fnmatch.fnmatch(name, 'B.csv'):
        b = name
        fileList.append(os.path.join(dirpath, name))
if a is not None and b is None:
    fileList.append(os.path.join(dirpath, a))
```

---

You can also combine the two approaches—break as soon as you find B.csv, and use a `for…else` followed by just `if a is not None:`.

---

As a side note, you don't need `fnmatch` if all you're doing is checking for an exact match. It's only necessary when you're matching glob patterns, like '*.csv' or the list. So you can simplify this quite a bit:

```
files = set(files)
if 'B.csv' in files:
    fileList.append(os.path.join(dirpath, 'B.csv'))
elif 'A.csv' in files:
    fileList.append(os.path.join(dirpath, 'A.csv'))
```

Comment: Nice for-else.  My first inclination is `b_files = [nm for nm in files if fnmatch.fnmatch(nm, 'B.csv')]`.  Then `if b_files:` append and `continue`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: Yeah, that's another way to do the two-pass solution. More concise, but one more thing to explain to the OP. If you really want to make it concise, you could do `file = next(chain((name for name in files if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, 'B.csv')), (name for name in files if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, 'A.csv'))), None)`… It would probably look nicer if `fnmatch` had been argclinic'd so you could use `filter(partial(fnmatch, pattern='B.csv'), files)`, but as far as I know in 3.5 it still only takes positional args.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Helped me work out my problem perfectly. Didn't realize I could use for with else like that. next-chain is also new to me. I'll have to play with it to see which is better, but for the time being for-else works

Comment: @stoves: `chain` is a function in the `itertools` module in the stdlib. If you understand iterators and generators and genexprs but haven't looked at `itertools` yet, definitely check it out. If you don't understand iterators and etc., the official tutorial has a pretty good introduction.

Comment: @stoves: As for `for…else`, in most cases it only saves maybe one line of code, and a lot of people aren't familiar with it, so I often try to avoid it… but occasionally a problem just seems to demand it, so it's worth learning.